# Visual Studio Intellisense for XSLT functions

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Is there any way to extend Visual Studio (i'm using 2012) intellisense to  support XSLT functions.

```
<xsl:if test="co  //i want a hint on available xslt 1.0 functions here
```

XSLT 1.0